# The Association Refers to the Owning Side Field Which Does Not Exist

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, sylius

I'm trying to add a many-to-many relationship between two existing entities in Sylius (ShopUser and Taxon). I've followed the Doctrine documentation on this, and thought I had everything set up correctly, but I get the following error:

> The association Sylius\Component\Core\Model\ShopUser#taxons refers to
>   the owning side field Sylius\Component\Taxonomy\Model\Taxon#shop_users
>   which does not exist.

Here's how I have things set up:

src/Sylius/Component/Taxonomy/Model/Taxon.php:

```
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;

class Taxon implements TaxonInterface {

    protected $shop_users;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->shop_users = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function getShopUsers() {
        return $this->shop_users;
    }

    public function addShopUser(ShopUser $user)
    {
        $user->addTaxon($this);
        $this->shop_users[] = $user;
    }

}
```

src/Sylius/Component/Core/Model/ShopUser.php:

```
namespace Sylius\Component\Core\Model;

use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;

class ShopUser extends BaseUser implements ShopUserInterface {

    protected $taxons;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->taxons = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function addTaxon(Taxon $taxon) {
        $this->taxons[] = $taxon; // Add the taxon to our collection of taxons available for this shop user
    }


    public function getTaxons() {
        return $this->taxons;
    }

}
```

src/Sylius/Bundle/TaxonomyBundle/Resources/config/doctrine/model/Taxon.orm.xml:

```
<many-to-many field="shop_users" inversed-by="taxons" target-entity="Sylius\Component\Core\Model\ShopUser">
    <join-table name="sylius_taxon_shop_user">
        <join-columns>
            <join-column name="taxon_id" referenced-column-name="id" />
        </join-columns>
        <inverse-join-columns>
            <join-column name="shop_user_id" referenced-column-name="id" />
        </inverse-join-columns>
    </join-table>
</many-to-many>
```

src/Sylius/Bundle/CoreBundle/Resources/config/doctrine/model/ShopUser.orm.xml:

```
<many-to-many field="taxons" mapped-by="shop_users" target-entity="Sylius\Component\Taxonomy\Model\Taxon" />
```

I've run the migration, and it successfully created the table 'sylius_taxon_shop_user' which has columns for taxon_id and shop_user_id.

I've done some reading on the many-to-many relationships, but can't seem to figure out why I'm getting the error.

***EDIT***:

the ShopUser model used to have this in the addTaxon code, which cauased an infinite loop:

```
$taxon->addShopUser($this); // Add this user to the taxon, as well (inverse side)
```

I've removed it now, but still get the same error.

***2nd EDIT***

I'd like to note that in commenting out the many-to-many tag in my ShopUser.orm.xml, the error changes and indicates that the mapping on the other side is also invalid:

> The association Sylius\Component\Core\Model\Taxon#shop_users refers to
>   the inverse side field Sylius\Component\Core\Model\ShopUser#taxons
>   which does not exist.